# Heavily unbalanced sampling design - Structure of GLMM (ecology)

Tags: correlation, mixed-model, unbalanced-classes, glmm, ecology

I am currently working on a dataset (count data) from a rather heavily unbalanced sampling design.
In particular, I would like to be able to predict the abundance of the studied species according to multiple landscape and meteorological metrics. To do so, I have tried to build GLMMs (with a negative binomial distribution) but I am having trouble finding a model structure that would fit the structure of my dataset.

This dataset consists of surveys (count data) carried out in three cities:

- In the city A, the protocol I was followed in year 7.
- In the city B, the protocol II was followed in years 1 to 6.
- In the city C, the protocol I was followed in year 4 and both the protocols I and II were followed in year 5.

In the protocol II, clusters of sites are monitored along transects, whereas in the protocol I, the sites should be located more or less randomly.
Furthermore, there can be several sites/transects monitored on a given day in a given city. Some sites/transects were also monitored several times during a year or during the whole sampling period.

| City | Protocole | Year | Number of transects | Number of sites | Number of surveys |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City A | Protocole I | Year 7 | NA | 73 | 73 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 1 | 18 | 167 | 242 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 2 | 22 | 206 | 310 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 3 | 11 | 103 | 103 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 4 | 8 | 64 | 74 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 5 | 8 | 75 | 95 |
| City B | Protocole II | Year 6 | 8 | 77 | 88 |
| City C | Protocole I | Year 4 | NA | 35 | 63 |
| City C | Protocole I | Year 5 | NA | 19 | 19 |
| City C | Protocole II | Year 5 | 13 | 71 | 71 |

Regarding this unbalanced structure, I first tried to build a model by city, e.g. for city B:
`Abundance ~ environmental variables + meteorological variables + Julian day (and its quadratic effect) + year (in factor) + (1 | transect / site) + (1 | date)`

However, for a number of reasons (including having sufficient statistical power), I have been advised to try to build a model for all the data (and not just for city subsets). This seems quite tricky to me, especially because of the high correlation between cities, protocols and years. I first imagined adding a random effect which would be a 10-level factor corresponding to the 10 combinations of city * protocol * year. However, I do not think this would be rigorous as the different levels would not be independent (e.g. one can assume that city B * protocol II * year 1 would give more similar results to city B * protocol II * year 2 than with city A * protocol I * year 7).

So my question is the following one:
Can anyone think of a model structure that would be able to encompass the variation due to city, protocol and year without having correlation issues (e.g. high VIF) or random effects with insufficient levels (e.g. 2 levels whereas I read that a minimum of about 6 would be much better)? Or is it just not possible?

For your information: I’m using R and I use the glmmTMB package.

UPDATE : Some additional information on the two protocols:

- Protocol II: during two given hours of the day, surveys are carried out along a transect consisting of at least 6 sites, each site being monitored for 6 minutes. The abundance at a given site is the number of individuals counted during the 6 minutes.
- Protocol I: a given site is monitored for the whole day. For this study, only the two hours during which the protocol II is carried out are considered, and the abundance is the average number of individuals counted during 6-minute intervals during these two hours.
  The device used to detect individuals are not the same in protocols I and II (with probably different performances).

Comment: I would imagine it's hard to do this without making some (perhaps reasonable) assumptions about the comparability of protocols. The fact that you have *some* data where both protocols were measured simultaneously will help, but it might be useful if you edited the question to add more information about the two protocols and their differences.

Comment: I added some information about the protocols to my question. Unfortunately, I am not very optimistic that the results obtained with each protocol are directly comparable...